# How to write Dynamic Values of Dictionary into csv python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a Dictionary where *Keys are static and Values are Dynamic*. I want to add those values into **CSV** file.

**Input is given below :-**

```
dictionary=[{
Name: f"{name of the person}",
Age: f"{Age of the person}",
Place:f"{place name}"
}]
```

**Field names are given below**

```
field_name=["Name","Age","Place"]
```

I want the csv like :

```
Name age place
A     1   Avc
B     2   Bds
C     3   Vsd
...   .. ....
...   .. ....
...   .. ....
```

But What I am getting is

```
Name age place
A     1   Avc
Name age place
B     2   Bds
Name age place
C     3   Vsd
Name age place
...  ..  ....
Name age place
...  ..  ....
```

My code to operate the csv is shown below.

```
with open("csv_can.csv","a",newline="") as f:
        writ= csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=field_names)
        writ.writeheader()
        writ.writerows(dictionary)
```

dictionary cointain Key:value pair and field_names contain Keys.
This code is running in a **while True** loop

Comment: can you provide one sample input and your desired output? It helps to understand the question better.

Comment: I have mentioned the desired output. I will provide you the input now.

Comment: dictionary = [{ Name: f"{A},
                       Age:f"{1},
                       Place:f{place_name}
                      }]

where the name age and place name changes dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending (by using `...th open("csv_can.c..."a",...ine=""...) as f:`) the header again and again. Just check (`if not os.path.isfile("csv_can.csv"):`)if the file already exists. If so don't write the header again.

```py
import csv
import os

A = 'A'
place_name = 'B'

dictionary = [{ 'Name': f'{A}', 'Age':f'{1}', 'Place':f'{place_name}'}]

field_names = ['Name', 'Age', 'Place']
with open("csv_can.csv","a",newline="") as f:
    writ= csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=field_names)
    if not os.path.isfile("csv_can.csv"):
        writ.writeheader()
    writ.writerows(dictionary)
```

Comment: Here what happens is I deleted the file and run the code. without header the values are printing.

Comment: I also just wrote the Headers separately so the code works. But then what happens, When I re-run the script, again the header is printing. I know its foolish Idea what i done, but I got no idea in that.

Comment: Yeah I got the Output as I desired. I just modified a little bit. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your question here, like @epsi95 said, please provide what is your sample and how it needs to be looked.meantime, try this if this can apply to you,

```
import pandas as pd
yourdict = {'A':'1','B':'2','C':'3'
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(list(yourdict .items()))
df.to_csv('yourcsv.csv')
```